# Why does this integral hold?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, economics

Given that $h_i(p,u) = \frac{de(p,u)}{p_i}$, why does this equality hold? $p^0$ is a vector $(p^0_1, p^0_2, p^0_3....)$ and $p^1$ is a vector $(p^1_1, p^1_2,....)$ . Shouldn't the upper bound and the lower bound switch in the first term? And why is the second term true?
[image]

Source: MGW Microeconomic Theory

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, and the solution that you attached have some minor errors.

Since it is a line integral, the following should be true.

$$
e(p^0, u^1) - e(p_1^1, p_2^0, p_3^0, \cdots, p_L^0, u^1) = 
\int_{p_1^1}^{p_1^0}h(p_1, p_2^0, p_3^0, \cdots, p_L^0, u^1)dp_1
$$
, or
$$
= 
-\int_{p_1^0}^{p_1^1}h(p_1, p_2^0, p_3^0, \cdots, p_L^0, u^1)dp_1
$$

However, note that the solution reaches the goal anyway because it makes the same mistake for the CV.

Instead, I will give you my corrected solution to the problem.

---

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
EV(p^0, p^1, w) & = e(p^0, u^1) - e(p^1, u^1) \\
 & = e(p^0, u^1) - e(p_1^1, p_2^0, p_3^0, \cdots, p_L^0, u^1) + e(p_1^1, p_2^0, p_3^0, \cdots, p_L^0, u^1) - e(p^1, u^1) \\ 
 & = \int_{p_1^1}^{p_1^0}h(p_1, p_2^0, p_3^0, \cdots, p_L^0, u^1)dp_1 + \int_{p_2^1}^{p_2^0}h(p_1^1, p_2, p_3^0, \cdots, p_L^0, u^1)dp_2 
\end{align}
$$

Moreover,
$$
\begin{align}
CV(p^0, p^1, w) & = e(p^0, u^0) - e(p^1, u^0) \\
 & = e(p^0, u^0) - e(p_1^1, p_2^0, p_3^0, \cdots, p_L^0, u^0) + e(p_1^1, p_2^0, p_3^0, \cdots, p_L^0, u^0) - e(p^1, u^0) \\ 
 & = \int_{p_1^1}^{p_1^0}h(p_1, p_2^0, p_3^0, \cdots, p_L^0, u^0)dp_1 + \int_{p_2^1}^{p_2^0}h(p_1^1, p_2, p_3^0, \cdots, p_L^0, u^0)dp_2 
\end{align}
$$

Now, under the no wealth effect, note that 
$$
h(p_1, p_2^0, p_3^0, \cdots, p_L^0, u^1) = h(p_1, p_2^0, p_3^0, \cdots, p_L^0, u^0) \textrm{  for every } p_1>0
$$
$$
h(p_1^1, p_2, p_3^0, \cdots, p_L^0, u^1) = h(p_1^1, p_2, p_3^0, \cdots, p_L^0, u^0) \textrm{  for every } p_2>0
$$

Therefore, we have
$$
EV(p^0, p^1, w) = CV(p^0, p^1, w)
$$
if there is no wealth effect.